# Problem with sizeof... of parameter pack in enable_if

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, sizeof, enable-if, parameter-pack

The following example fails in all major compilers: `clang`, `gcc` and `visual studio`.

I would like to know what's wrong with it, it seems to be to be very simple:

if `sizeof...(TYPES) == 2` then it should exclude one overload and accept the other one, if 0, 1 or greater than 2 then it should accept the first overload
and exclude the 2nd one.

Why doesn't this work this way?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... TYPES>
struct Test {
    template <std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(TYPES) != 2), int> = 0>
    Test() {
        std::cout << "A\n";
    }

    template <std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(TYPES) == 2), int> = 0>
    Test() {
        std::cout << "B\n";
    }
};

int
main() {

    Test<int, int> t1;
    Test<int, int, int> t2;

    return 0;
}
```

`clang` error:

```
In file included from C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\iostream:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\istream:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\ostream:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\ios:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xlocnum:12:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cmath:505:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xtgmath.h:13:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xtr1common:54:40: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, int>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Test, _Ty>::type;
                                       ^~~~~
C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp:6:17: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'enable_if_t' requested here
        template <std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(TYPES) != 2), int> = 0>
                       ^
C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp:20:17: note: in instantiation of template class 'Test<int, int>' requested here
        Test<int, int> t1;
                       ^
In file included from C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\iostream:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\istream:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\ostream:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\ios:11:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xlocnum:12:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\cmath:505:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xtgmath.h:13:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xtr1common:54:40: error: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, int>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Test, _Ty>::type;
                                       ^~~~~
C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp:11:17: note: in instantiation of template type alias 'enable_if_t' requested here
        template <std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(TYPES) == 2), int> = 0>
                       ^
C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp:21:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'Test<int, int, int>' requested here
        Test<int, int, int> t2;
                            ^
2 errors generated.
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

`gcc` error:

```
C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct Test<int, int>':
C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp:20:17:   required from here
C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp:7:2: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, int>'
  Test() {
  ^~~~
C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct Test<int, int, int>':
C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp:21:22:   required from here
C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\tests\par_pack.cpp:12:2: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, int>'
  Test() {
  ^~~~
[Finished in 2.1s]
```

`visual studio` error:

```
1>C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\A++\A++\main.cpp(160,1): error C2938: 'std::enable_if_t<false,int>' : Failed to specialize alias template
1>C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\A++\A++\main.cpp(159): message : see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::enable_if_t<false,int>' being compiled
1>C:\Users\joaopires\Dropbox\++A\A++\A++\main.cpp(208): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Test<int,int,int>' being compiled
1>Done building project "A++.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: What are the problems you have with the code you show? What doe you mean when you say it "doesn't [...] work this way"? Do you get build errors? Then please copy-paste them (as text) into the question itself, in full and complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not work since your template-member-functions SFINAE on the template parameter from the class. SFINAE only works on types and expressions in the immediate context, here that means template parameter that belong to the constructors template signature.

To get around this we can introduce a new template parameter in the constructor and give it a default value that depends on the class-template.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... TYPES>
struct Test {
    template <std::size_t i = sizeof...(TYPES), std::enable_if_t<i != 2, int> = 0>
    Test() {
        std::cout << "A\n";
    }

    template <std::size_t i = sizeof...(TYPES), std::enable_if_t<i == 2, int> = 0>
    Test() {
        std::cout << "B\n";
    }
};

int
main() {

    Test<int, int> t1;
    Test<int, int, int> t2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `C++` sure is filled with weird corners.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++20, you might use `requires` to discard unwanted constructor:

```
template <typename... TYPES>
struct Test {
    Test() requires(sizeof...(TYPES) != 2) { std::cout << "A\n"; }
    Test() requires(sizeof...(TYPES) == 2) { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};
```

Even if in that case a simple `if` (`constexpr`) would do the job:

```
template <typename... TYPES>
struct Test {
    Test()
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(TYPES) != 2) {
            std::cout << "A\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "B\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Or even go all the way down to `std::cout << (sizeof...(TYPES) != 2 ? "A\n" : "B\n");`?